# Files are still accessible after they've been deleted in Google Cloud Storage, or when a new file with the same name has been uploaded

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storage and asp.net core 6.

To configure the Google cloud storage I used this article:
https://medium.com/net-core/using-google-cloud-storage-in-asp-net-core-74f9c5ee55f5

Uploading and deleting a file all work fine.

The only problem I'm experiencing is that when I delete a file, that file is still accessible. (when I look in the bucket I can see that the file is actually gone).

So I tried deleting it manually on the Google cloud platform, but I keep getting the same problem. The image is still visible with the link.

Even when I upload a new image with the same name as the old one, when displaying or downloading the image it's still the old image.

I tried with different browsers, in case it might have something to do with caching but that didn't help either.

I also checked object versioning was off.

I can also see that inside the bucket the 'created date' does in fact change.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled on the object(s) in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the object is being stored in cache (either Google's cache, your browsers or potentially any proxy in-between).

Publicly shared objects [default to being cacheable for 1 hour](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching#built-in_caching_for). After this, changes should be visible. If that is not acceptable to you [set](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) `Cache-Control` header/metadata to a shorter time or `no-store`.

Comment: Yes indeed, I found an answer, By creating Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object object and initializing 'CacheControl = "private,max-age=0,no-store"' like this the objects are not cached anymore.

Comment: I'm unclear about the consequence of setting no-store. Clearly, local cache still works, so implications for browser users are minimal. Why doesn't  Google make no-cache the default? Whatever the reason might be, the confusion highlighted by Niels' question is surely more significant.

Comment: Plus, while 'CacheControl = "private,max-age=0,no-store" works, as Niels says, it doesn't seem that you can set this on a bucket using the Cloud console and expect to have this setting inherited by every file you create inside it - you seem to have to set metadata on each individual file as you create it. This is hard work!

Comment: This is a particular problem since it implies that my webapp users will have to have 'storage.objects.update access' and I'm not sure how I'm going to give them this (or whether I want to!)

Comment: You can also just avoid updating files by making new versions use a new filename and reference that instead. Cache will not apply if you can do that.